# Standard for determining accuracy of polygon interpolation technique?

Tags: interpolation

I'm looking into polygon interpolation, and was curious if there are any standards for determining the accuracy of polygon interpolation techniques. I've been looking through papers and lecturers slides and have found a [reference](http://paulbolstad.cfans.umn.edu/Courses/FR3131/LecSupp/Interpolation_3131.pdf) (page 6) to removing sample points from the interpolation as a measure of accuracy. I've also found a [paper](http://www.isprs.org/proceedings/XXXV/congress/comm2/papers/231.pdf) (page 6) where they are using min, max, mean, and standard deviation as measures of accuracy. So, is there a standard out there for measure the accuracy of interpolation. Any published papers would be a big help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Method for estimating accuracy in spatial interpolation?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73241/method-for-estimating-accuracy-in-spatial-interpolation)